# How does this javascript snippet work?

Tags: javascript

I wrote myself a Javascript function for appending Javascript files to the DOM, I'm fairly new to javascript and as such my solution was fairly verbose. So after a little googling I found this seemingly really cool trick for appending javascript files. Now I'm reluctant to replace my code with the cool new trick till I fully understand how it functions.

Here's the new code.

```
!function(b){function c(){if(d=e.shift())a=b.body.appendChild(b.createElement("SCRIPT")),a.onload=c,a.src=d}var e=[
  'https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MY_API_KEY',
  'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initPicker'
],a,d;c()}(document);
```

Please could someone clear up just what is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the code you've presented does the same as the following, which I hope is more readable:

```
function loadAllJavaScriptFiles() {
    function loadNextJavaScriptFile(){
        var nextUrl = urls.shift();
        if (nextUrl) {
            var scriptElement = document.body.appendChild(
                                    document.createElement("SCRIPT"));
            scriptElement.onload = loadNextJavaScriptFile;
            scriptElement.src = nextUrl;
        }
    }

    var urls = ['https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MY_API_KEY',
                'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initPicker'];
    loadNextJavaScriptFile();
}

loadAllJavaScriptFiles();
```

`a` is now `scriptElement`, function `c` is now `loadNextJavaScriptFile`, `d` is now `nextUrl` and `e` is now `urls`.  `b` was only used to abbreviate `document`.  The outer `function` never had a name; I've called it `loadAllJavaScriptFiles`.

The snippet iterates through a number of URLs that presumably return JavaScript code, and creates `<script>` elements to load this JavaScript code onto the page.  The JavaScript is loaded one URL at a time in the order specified in `urls`: the `onload` handler for one script file is used to trigger the process of loading the next.

The inner code is wrapped in an [immediately-invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).  The code in this method runs immediately, and because it's inside a `function` it avoids changing the values of any variables in your own JavaScript code that happen to have the same names.

Comment: +1 for detailing that the function is self invoking by being preceded with a unary character `!function(b){}`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code slightly cleaned up.

```
  function c(){
    var e=['https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MY_API_KEY', 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initPicker']
    var a,d;
    if(d=e.shift()) {
      a=document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("SCRIPT"))
      a.onload=c
      a.src=d
    }
   }
```

I'm guessing it will iterate over the elements in `e` and create SCRIPT elements for them in the document.

Do you have any additional documentation to this snippet?

Comment: Nope I just found the snippet on twitter, hence my reluctance to use it, even though it works.

Comment: so does `if(d=e.shift())` only evaluate to true if the array in e has an element to return ?

Comment: @Luke: Basically yes: if `e` has no element to return, `shift` returns `undefined` (see [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.9)), which is evaluated as `false` by the `if` statement.